# How to consistently horizontally align text across lines with a consistent horizontal gap in each line?

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I have something like this:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{p{\linewidth}}
  \textit{SOME LABEL}\hspace{1em}Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit $x_1 \ldots x_n$. \\
  \textit{SOME LABEL}\hspace{1em}Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin.
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

It ultimately looks like:
[image]

The first line breaks early and is justified because I guess it didn't want a line break in the middle of math mode. However, this causes "SOME LABEL" and "Lorem" to be misaligned with the row below.

How can I disable justification of "SOME LABEL" so that its horizontal edges always align across lines? Furthermore, how can I make the gap between it and the subsequent sentence consistent? I'd still like for the rest of the paragraph to be justified as usual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get consistent spacing if you use `\raggedright` (either manually, with every cell in your table, or through an automated `>{\raggedright}` fashion thanks to [`array`](//ctan.org/pkg/array)). But if you wish to keep the spacing for `SOME LABEL` fixed, set it in a box (either `\mbox` or `\makebox`). However, I almost feel you need to set a list (using `description`, for example).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array,enumitem}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{} p{\linewidth} @{}}
  \textit{SOME LABEL}\quad Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit $x_1 \ldots x_n$. \\
  \textit{SOME LABEL}\quad Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin.
\end{tabular}

\medskip

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{} p{\linewidth} @{}}
  \mbox{\textit{SOME LABEL}}\quad Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit $x_1 \ldots x_n$. \\
  \mbox{\textit{SOME LABEL}}\quad Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin.
\end{tabular}

\medskip

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{} p{\linewidth} @{}}
  \raggedright
  \textit{SOME LABEL}\quad Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit $x_1 \ldots x_n$. \\
  \raggedright
  \textit{SOME LABEL}\quad Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin.
\end{tabular}

\medskip

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{} >{\raggedright}p{\linewidth} @{}}
  \textit{SOME LABEL}\quad Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit $x_1 \ldots x_n$. \\
  \textit{SOME LABEL}\quad Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin.
\end{tabular}

\medskip

\begin{description}[font=\normalfont\itshape]
  \item[SOME LABEL]
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit $x_1 \ldots x_n$.
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit $x_1 \ldots x_n$.
  
  \item[SOME LABEL]
  Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin.
  Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin.
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

Comment: In practice, the table needs another column to the left, so I don't think a list would work. It'd be a nice solution otherwise. I can't get `\raggedright` to work with 2 columns: `\begin{tabular}{p{0.5\linewidth} p{0.5\linewidth}}a & \raggedright b \\ c & \raggedright d\end{tabular}` yields "Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr." Apologies for not mentioning the 2nd column; I figured it wouldn't change the solution since misalignment occurs even outside a table.

Comment: @bgfvdu3w: Try with `\raggedright\arraybackslash`. And note that your table width will exceed `\linewidth`, even if you think that two `0.5\linewidth` columns will fit; there are `\tabcolsep`s around every column.

Comment: That worked! Good call on the width; I excluded the `@{}` in an attempt to make the inline code more readable. Why did you mention `\mbox`? "SOME LABEL" seems to have fixed spacing without it.

Comment: @bgfvdu3w: ...when you use `\raggedright`. Under normal justification `\mbox` will ensure the "original spacing" is preserved.